# unable to connect to internet from terminal on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I don't get whats the problem but when i try to run the following command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I was getting an output of sort...

```
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.184)] 
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.184)] 
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.184)] 
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.184)]
```

and so on... but unable to download anything... :(...

I updated my `resolv.conf` file and is as follows:

`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)

    #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

    nameserver 8.8.8.8`

the routing table looks like:

```
Kernel IP routing table                                                                                         
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface                                   
0.0.0.0         172.30.100.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0                                    
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0                                    
172.30.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

My wired connection configuration is like this:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:9a:8f:0b:25:57                                                         
      inet addr:172.30.100.42  Bcast:172.30.101.255  Mask:255.255.254.0                                     
      inet6 addr: fe80::ea9a:8fff:fe0b:2557/64 Scope:Link                                                   
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                    
      RX packets:201591 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                               
      TX packets:54761 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1                                              
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                                                          
      RX bytes:53827641 (53.8 MB)  TX bytes:7677456 (7.6 MB)                                                
      Interrupt:44
```

And our institute uses a proxy server... when i try to ping that server it was pinging these servers but not the external servers...like `security.ubuntu.com` or some other site... I can access `internet` from my browser, but the `software center` is unable to download anything.

I have set the system-proxy also..
Plz help....

Comment: Have you tried running `traceroute us.archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: yea but still it wasn't working...

Answer (score 1):

The IP address starting with "169" in your routing table is an APIPA (Auto Private IP Address) and it should raise a red flag every time you see it. It means that your computer gave up trying to contact a DHCP server for a legitimate IP address. In a good LAN setup, I've found this is usually due to an unplugged patch cable. Also make sure your computer has the correct address for your DHCP server.

However "172" is a valid private IP address for your eth0.

**Important**: Do not edit your resolv.conf file!

Make the changes for dns-search, dns-nameservers, static IP address, subnet mask, etc. in  the
`/etc/network/interfaces` file. To keep things simple, reboot after you make your changes or learn how to use *ifdown* and *ifup*

Your best bet is to search Google for your Ubuntu version and keywords such as "editing resolv.conf," "adding nameservers," and so forth.